# Extension methods on Eval()

Tags: .net, vb.net, data-binding, .net-4.0, extension-methods

I have an extension method like this:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function Trim(value As Object, MaxLength As Integer) As String
    If value IsNot Nothing AndAlso value.ToString.Length > MaxLength Then
        Return value.ToString.Substring(0, MaxLength)
    Else
        Return value.ToString
    End If
End Function
```

My assumption was that I could then go `Eval("MyColumnName").Trim(20)` when databinding (Rather then doing things like MyMethod(Eval("MyColumnName")) but this has proved incorrect.

Is there any way to use extension on the Eval method?

PS: I have my extensions referenced as a global reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that while you can extend the `Object` type, you can't use a variable of type `Object` to call the method.

[MSDN Magazine: Basic Instincts: Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163317.aspx#S6)

```
Dim myString As String = "ABC123"
Dim myObject As Object = "ABC123"
Dim myResult as String

myResult = myString.Trim(3)  ' Works
myResult = myObject.Trim(3)  ' Fails
```

So I think the best you could hope for in a one-liner is:

```
Eval("MyColumnName").ToString.Trim(20)
```